# Вопрос про правильное написание окончаний причастий

Tags: орфография

Слово *истраченный* — от слова *истратить*, 2-е спряжение, но в слове *истрачЕнный* пишется *е*. Почему? Аналогично и со словами *застроенный*, *замороженный* (*застроить*, *заморозить*).
Обидевший — от слова обидеть — это слово-исключение, надо писать *и*, но опять же пишется *обидЕвший*.
Слово *ненавидимый* — *ненавидеть* (слово-исключение), пишем *и*, а тут пишется уже *ненавидимый*, но почему же слово *обидЕвший* пишется через *е*, хотя это такое же исключение, как *ненавидеть* (*ненавидимый*).
И ещё вопрос — *сможешь* или *сможишь* (т. е. какое правило надо знать)?